# Programmatic Layout Margins aren't working

Tags: android, android-layout, margins

I've been trying to separate 3 EditTexts from each other with a small margin in between. However, i've been unsuccessful. I've googled a lot and tried multiple different options, but this is the closest i can find to give me my result.

I want the second line of "Item Part No." to look like the first line. The closest i can get is a small gap between "Item Part No." and "Q", but "Q" and "RRP" still remain squished together. To do this i remove the "Params3" linear layout. But for now i'm keeping it in, but they all touch together.

The first line is done in the XML Layout so i know how i wanted it to look.

[image]

Below is the code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.7f);
            params.setMargins(0,0,10,10);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.15f);
            params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 10);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.15f);
            params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 10);


            LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(Home.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            LL.setWeightSum(1f);
            LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

            EditText partNo = new EditText(Home.this);
            partNo.setId(View.generateViewId());
            partNo.setLayoutParams(params);
            partNo.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            partNo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textinputborder);
            partNo.setSingleLine(true);
            partNo.setHint("Item Part No.");
            LL.addView(partNo);

            EditText partqua = new EditText(Home.this);
            partqua.setId(View.generateViewId());
            partqua.setLayoutParams(params2);
            partqua.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            partqua.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textinputborder);
            partqua.setSingleLine(true);
            partqua.setHint("Q");
            LL.addView(partqua);

            EditText itemPri = new EditText(Home.this);
            itemPri.setId(View.generateViewId());
            itemPri.setLayoutParams(params3);
            itemPri.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            itemPri.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textinputborder);
            itemPri.setSingleLine(true);
            itemPri.setHint("RRP");
            LL.addView(itemPri);

            mLayout.addView(LL);
```

Here is the XML used for the first row. I've tried changing the margins to match those of the XML and unfortunately the gaps still don't appear between Edit Texts.

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/items"
                    >

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
                        android:id="@+id/r1i1name"
                        android:layout_weight=".7"
                        android:hint="Item Part No."
                        android:singleLine="true"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
                        android:id="@+id/r1i1quant"
                        android:layout_weight=".15"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:hint="Q"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
                        android:id="@+id/r1i1price"
                        android:layout_weight=".15"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:hint="RRP"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Solved

Thanks to rajen-raiyarela for telling me about the LayoutInflator.

Home.java

```
plusItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.room1);

            view = LayoutInflater.from(Home.this).inflate(R.layout.newitem, parent, false);
            view.generateViewId();
            parent.addView(view);
        }
    });
```

newitem.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
        android:id="@+id/r1i1name"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:hint="Item Part No."
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
        android:id="@+id/r1i1quant"
        android:layout_weight=".07"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:hint="Q"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
        android:id="@+id/r1i1price"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:hint="RRP"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is first row added through layout.xml? if so pl share your layout.xml as well

Comment: If you already have xml set up, then simplest and feasible approach is to reuse this same xml to render new rows. Use LayoutInflator to inflate this xml as view and add the view to your main layout.

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't realise that existed. I'll give it a shot and see how i go.

Comment: Create a new xml layout with linearlayout parent with vertical orientation which will be used for rendering the main screen, in this new xml layout, include the above layout using include tag. So your first row will be created. Then for each new item create a new view from above xml and add to newly created layout with linearlayout parent.

Comment: as Rajen said, reuse the xml if you could, it is easier and cleaner code.
If you still want to do it programmaticaly, then try to add LayoutParam when you call the addView() to look like this "LL.addView(partqua, param2);"

Comment: If i use the LayoutInflator, then how do i set the android:id="" for them? I ask this as i'll be getting the edittexts data later on and figured i would need the Id's/pulling them from an edittext array.